# JVM allocation for multiple domain in Weblogic server

Tags: jvm, weblogic

If I create 3 domains for a Weblogic server and configure each setDomainEnv to use min Heap Size of 4096m(Xms) and max of 8192m(Xmx) then will that throw an error for the 64 bit JVM. I have a machine with 8GB RAM.

I get the error as :
Could not Create the Java Virtual Machine.
Minimum heap size invalid.

Comment: Can you paste the flags you use.

Comment: set USER_MEM_ARGS=-Xms4096m -Xmx8192m -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m

Comment: Can you do a java -version and paste it here? I suspect you are either using a 32bit Java or have installed it as 32 bit. 
Can you try doing this 
set USER_MEM_ARGS="-Xms4096m -Xmx8192m -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m"

Answer (score 0):

your machine has 8GB RAM in the sense system will use 7.X GB of RAM. So try to reduce the MAX heap size to available RAM so that issue will be resolved

Answer (score 0):

If you have a machine with 8GB you should think that the sum of memory used by the 3 domains cannot be more then 8GB.

Total memory = OS memory + domain 1 memory + domain 2 memory + domain 3 memory

You should not forget that in order to run those JVM's the operationg system needs memory as well.

I would recommend to start all those 3 domain with the same min and max memory 2GB

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/perform/JVMTuning.html